# native query join in spring data

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have the class:

```
@Entity
public class User {
    @Id
    Long id;
    String name;

    @ManyToMany
    List<Mission> missions;
}

@Entity
public class Mission {
    @Id
    Long id;
    String name;

    @ManyToMany
    List<User> users;
}

public interface MissionRepository extends CrudRepository<Mission, Long> {
    @Query(nativeQuery = true, "select * from mission join user on id = user_id where name = ?1")
    public List<Mission> findByname(String name);
}
```

I want to know if it's possible to use a native query join in spring data JPA and if the result of query was correctly mapped into entities like the above example.

Can someone show me a complete example to user this. 
I must to use a native query  in my case and I am not sure that work.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you can do that by using named native query and result set mapping
and here is a complete exmaple

Mission Entity

```
package com.ntg.crm.internal.entites;

import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.EntityResult;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.FieldResult;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.NamedNativeQuery;
import javax.persistence.SqlResultSetMapping;

@SqlResultSetMapping(name = "Mission.findAllMissionsMapping", entities = @EntityResult(entityClass = Mission.class, fields = {
        @FieldResult(name = "name", column = "mname"), @FieldResult(name = "id", column = "mid")
}))
@NamedNativeQuery(name = "Mission.findAllMissions", query = "select m.id as mid,m.name as mname , info.id uid ,info.name uname from Mission m join user_info_missions um on m.id "
        + "= um.missions_id join user_Info info on info.id = um.user_id where info.name =:userName", resultSetMapping = "Mission.findAllMissionsMapping")

@Entity
public class Mission {

    public Mission() {

    }

    public Mission(BigInteger id, String name) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Mission(BigInteger id, String name, List<User> users) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.users = users;
    }

    @Id
    BigInteger id;
    String name;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "user_info_missions", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "missions_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"))
    List<User> users;

    public BigInteger getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(BigInteger id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public List<User> getUsers() {
        return users;
    }

    public void setUsers(List<User> users) {
        this.users = users;
    }

}
```

User Entity

```
package com.ntg.crm.internal.entites;

import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;

@Entity
@Table(name = "userInfo")
public class User {

    @Id
    long id;
    String name;

    @ManyToMany(targetEntity = Mission.class)
    @JoinTable(name = "user_info_missions", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "missions_id"))
    @JsonIgnore
    List<Mission> missions;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public List<Mission> getMissions() {
        return missions;
    }

    public void setMissions(List<Mission> missions) {
        this.missions = missions;
    }

}
```

Repository Function

```
public List<Mission> findAllMissions(@Param("userName") String userName);
```

Controller Function

```
@Autowired
    TestRepository testRepo;

    @RequestMapping(value = "", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json", consumes = "application/json")
    @ResponseBody
    List<Mission> getall() {
        List<Mission> missions = testRepo.findAllMissions("Test");
        return missions;
    }
```

and this is The Result

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Mission 1",
    "users": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Test"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Mission 2",
    "users": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Test"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, but i want know if the result of query  mapped correctly  into entitie Mission. in other words can i get list of users  after this request.

Comment: Great example!  BTW, you can use Lombok annotations (like @Data) to reduce getter/setter and other boilerplate from entity.

Answer (score 1):

@middy62 you can use the query below. I have used your example to write the query. Hope it helps someone.

---

`@Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "select m from Mission join m.user u where name =:name")
public List<Mission> findByname(@Param("name") String name);`

Kindly note that the query works when you do you mappings correctly on the domain Entity models.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Native Spring Data JPA and use the join. This will return the array of objects

```java
public interface MissionRepository extends Repository<Mission, Long> {

@Query(value = "SELECT * from mission m 
                inner join user u 
                on m.id = u.id 
                where m.name=:name", nativeQuery = true)
List<Object[]> findByname(@Param("name") string name);
}
```