# Query from another perspective

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I've got four entities in my project:
`Topic`, `Article`, `Comment` and `Notification`.

> One `topic` can have multiple `articles`.
>
> One `article` can have multiple `comments`.
>
> You can add multiple `notifications` for `comment`.

Those are my entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "topics")
public class Topic {

    @Id
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private String description;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "article")
    private List<Article> articles;
    //getters & setters ommited
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "articles")
public class Article {

    @Id
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private String description;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "topic_id")
    private Topic topic;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "comment")
    private List<Comment> comments;
    //getters & setters ommited
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "comments")
public class Comment {
    @Id
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private String description;
    private LocalDateTime createDate;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "article_id")
    private Article article;
    //getters & setters ommited
}
```

And last one:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "notifications")
public class Notification {
    @Id
    private Integer id;
    private LocalDate date;
    private String description;
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "comment_id", nullable = false)
    private Comment comment;
    //getters & setters ommited
}
```

Now what I try to achive is to get set of topics with notifications between dates.

I even created a solution:

```
public Set<Topic> getTopicsWithNotificationsBetweenDates(LocalDate begin, LocalDate end) {
    return notificationRepository.findByDateBetween(begin, end)
            .stream()
            .map(notification-> getTopic(notification)))
            .collect(Collectors.toSet());
}

private Topic getTopic(Notification notification){
    return notification.getComment().getArticle().getTopic();
}
```

But this solution loop through all `notification` to get `topics`(and obviously there are repetitions). Getting them from customer side would've save a lot of time and effort in case there would've be e.g. `100 notifications` and only e.g. `5 topics`.

Now what I'm trying to do is loop through `topics` instead of `notifications`, but I do not have idea how could I query should look like.
I will be grateful for even a small help or atleast a point to the right direction.

Comment: @OneToMany(mappedBy = "customer")
    private List<Project> projects; is this requried here to understand the problem?

Comment: Thanks. Changed question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about adding of a bi-directional relation between a `Comment` and `Notification` entities? Then you will be able to do what you want in a single query like this:

```
List<Topic> findByArticlesCommentsNotificationsDateBetween(begin, end);
```

Comment: I'm curious is there a way to do it without doing relations?

Comment: I think it's possible by using native queries. [Here is a nice example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40960835/native-query-join-in-spring-data)